# Measuring Liquid with Augmented Reality Concept

Tags: android, ios, mobile, augmented-reality

Is measuring liquids possible with Augmented Reality?

For Example; A Glass of wine or a gallon of water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you searched this before asking your question? Looks like people have written articles about this subject matter. Read these two links:

http://www.icg.tugraz.at/publications/pdf/SpatialMeasurements

http://proceedings.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=1830279

I don't know so much in detail about augmented reality, but I suppose you can do that at least for known liquids like water, milk, etc. where we know the density and can do further calculations based on that, to measure volumes.